# Questions about entity type when using Freebase

Tags: entity, sparql, freebase, knowledge-graph

I am confused about that an entity in Freebase has many types , how can i know what is the type expressed in certain sub knowledge graph. for example,there is a subgraph :
`['m.0f010_', 'food.dish.cuisine', 'm.042ck']`
,entity `'m.042ck'` has the following types:
`['base.food_menu.regional_cuisine', 'base.food_menu.summary_cuisine', 'base.ontologies.ontology_instance', 'book.book_subject', 'business.industry', 'common.topic', 'dining.cuisine', 'organization.organization_sector']`
how can i get to know which type is expressed in the subgraph?

i use the following Sparql to query entity type ,is there any ways to do that

```
 sql = '''PREFIX fb: <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/> 
select  ?o1 where {
         fb:%s fb:type.object.type ?o1.
         } '''%entity
```

Comment: not sure if I understand. Your data is a set of RDF triples contained in a separate graph?

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the English labels for those topics are [Monjayaki](https://www.google.com/search?kgmid=/m/0f010_) and [Japanese cuisine](https://www.google.com/search?kgmid=/m/042ck).

Unless your sub-graph partitioned the type space, that entity has *all* of the listed types, although some of them wouldn't be considered significant. Any type with the `base.` prefix belongs to a part of the type system created by an individual user. Since they're not community vetted/approved, they can be ignored for most purposes. The type `common.topic` is assigned to basically everything that's not an internal housekeeping entity, so has little value.

Note that Freebase was crowdsourced, like Wikidata, so it may represent a more casual world view than a professional ontologist would use. Also, the final snapshot represents a single point in time of an evolving knowledge graph.

In this particular case, there are arguably at least two different entities conflated:

1. 'business.industry', 'organization.organization_sector'
2. 'dining.cuisine'

either of which can be used as a 'book.book_subject' which is more a declaration of a usage than an entity type.

In the context of your stated triple, with the predicate 'food.dish.cuisine', the most relevant type is 'dining.cuisine' because that's the "expected type", per this triple:

```
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/food.dish.cuisine>  <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/type.property.expected_type>        <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/dining.cuisine>
```

If you can answer @UninformedUser's question asking about the subgraph, we may be able to offer additional detail.